# I want to return an error when someone inputs a range which already exists in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> this is the code that contains the range slider

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Range.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ReactSlider from "react-slider";

function Range(props) {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(0);
  return (
    <RangeComp>
      <ReactSlider
        className="customSlider"
        trackClassName="customSlider-track"
        thumbClassName="customSlider-thumb"
        marks={1}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        defaultValue={0}
        value={currentValue}
        onChange={(value) => setCurrentValue(value)}
      />
      <Texts>
        <H4>{props.title}</H4>
        <H1>{currentValue}/10</H1>
      </Texts>
    </RangeComp>
  );
}

export default Range;
```

> i want to return an error that says you cannot have two values of 5, and then the slider returns >default position but i dont know how to go about it

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ellipse from "../img/ellipse.png";
import Range from "./Range";

function RangeComp() {
  const titlesArr = [
    "Cybersecurity",
    "Developer",
    "DevOps",
    "Designer",
    "Project Manager",
    "Product Manager",
    "Marketer",
    "Writer",
  ];
  console.log(titlesArr);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Circle />
      <Heading>Score your level of interest in these job titles:</Heading>
      <Divs>
        <Div1>
          <Range title={titlesArr[0]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[1]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[2]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[3]} />
        </Div1>
        <Div2>
          <Range title={titlesArr[4]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[5]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[6]} />
          <Range title={titlesArr[7]} />
        </Div2>
      </Divs>
      <Button>Done</Button>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default RangeComp;
```

> This is where im using the Range component im using it 8  times so i want >to return a function whereby if the value for two ranges are the same then >the error loads up

Comment: Where is another value? I only can see you have a value in ReactSlider only

Comment: Yes soo i want to return an error when two values from the reactslider are the same. I just made an edit to the question and added the code where m using the component so you can understand a bit better

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is if your code is too bulky, try to use the map method for the rendering of your component, for the checking you could use the filter method. Here's a sample code for your reference.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ellipse from "../img/ellipse.png";
import Range from "./Range";

function RangeComp() {
  const titlesArr = [
    "Cybersecurity",
    "Developer",
    "DevOps",
    "Designer",
    "Project Manager",
    "Product Manager",
    "Marketer",
    "Writer",
  ];

  // this variables remove all the duplicates in your array
  const cleanTitlesArr = titlesArr.filter((item, index) => arry.indexOf(item) === index)

  console.log(titlesArr);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Circle />
      <Heading>Score your level of interest in these job titles:</Heading>
      <Divs>
        // this code here solve the problem of your code being bulky
        {cleanTitlesArr.map((title, index) => (
            <Range key={index} title={title} />
        ))}
      </Divs>
      <Button>Done</Button>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default RangeComp;
```